# Adding the Apache Commons Net library to Eclipse

Tags: java, jar

I have added the Apache Commons Net library to Eclipse by including the commons-net-3.1.jar in a bin folder within my project, and then adding it as a library in the Java build path. All seems well, except when I export my jar file org.apache.commons.net is not included in the jar file.

Is there some other means of configuring to be done, so that my jar file will include the commons net?

Answer (score 1):

You won't include commons-net-3.1.jar inside your jar, but instead you will want to reference it via the `classpath`

```
java -classpath .;path/to/commons-net-3.1.jar my.package.MainClass
```

You may wish to, instead, use a manifest file inside your jar file.  It should look like this:

```
Class-Path: path/to/commons-net-3.1.jar
```

Comment: thanx - The method I have used does add commons net to class path:

Answer (score 1):

Export it as a runnable jar instead.  There are several options depending on how you want the jars files to be treated.